# How to save in a polymorphic relationship in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, orm, polymorphism

I'm reading the tutorial* on how to define many-to-many polymorphic relationships in Laravel but it doesn't show how to save records with this relationship.

In the their example they have

```
class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the tags for the post.
     */
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Tag', 'taggable');
    }
}
```

and

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the posts that are assigned this tag.
     */
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Post', 'taggable');
    }

    /**
     * Get all of the videos that are assigned this tag.
     */
    public function videos()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Video', 'taggable');
    }
}
```

I've tried saving in different ways but the attempts that makes most sense to me is:

```
$tag = Tag::find(1);
$video = Video::find(1);
$tag->videos()->associate($video);

or

$tag->videos()->sync($video);
```

None of these are working. Can anyone give me a clue on what I could try?

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It's simple like that, see [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models) section.

> Instead of manually setting the attribute on the videos, you may insert the Comment directly from the relationship's save method:

```
//Create a new Tag instance (fill the array with your own database fields)
$tag = new Tag(['name' => 'Foo bar.']);

//Find the video to insert into a tag
$video = Video::find(1);

//In the tag relationship, save a new video
$tag->videos()->save($video);
```

Comment: If it's not work, edit your post and explain your relationship for us

Comment: Thank you. That fixed it. I was so close.

Comment: @João Mantovani Seems you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49512956/how-can-i-add-delete-and-get-a-favorite-from-product-with-polymorphic-relations

Comment: @JoãoMantovani how it is possible that u have videos() relation on the tag() model if tag() is the polymorphic model with taggable() morphTo()?

Comment: Instead of `$tag->videos()->save($videos)` do `$video->tags()->save($tag)` because the video model has many tags and setup `morphTo` in your `video` model.

Answer (score 23):

you missed a step in the associate method, use this:

```
$tag->videos()->associate($video)->save();
```

Comment: Only this one works for me

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this which worked for me (morphMany):

```
$rel_data = ['assigned_type'=>'User','assigned_id'=>$user_model->getKey()];

$event->assigned_models()->create($rel_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to save multi tags you can use code below

route:

```
Route::post('posts/{id}/tags', 'PostController@storeTags');
```

your request sends tags as array contains ids

```
+ Request (application/json) or (form-data)
        {
            "tags": [
              1,2,3,4
            ]
        }
```

in your controller:

```
public function storeTags(Request $request, $id)
{
    foreach ($request->tags as $id)
        $tags[] = Tag::find($id);

    $post= Post::find($id);
    $post->tags()->saveMany($tags);

}
```

and for update:

```
// sync() works with existing models' ids. [here means: $request->tags]
$post->tags()->sync([1,2,3]); // detaches all previous relations
$post->tags()->sync([1,2,3], false); // does not detach previous relations,attaches new ones skipping existing ids
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code:

```
$post->comments->attach($comment);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Comment.php

```
class Comment extends Model
{
use HasFactory;
protected $fillable = ['body','comment_id','comment_type'];
public function commentable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
}
```

> MainController.php

```
 public function addPost(){
    //add Post
    //Create a new Tag instance (fill the array with your own database fields)
    $post = new Post(['post_name' => 'something post ']);
    
    //Find the comment to insert into a post
    $comment =  Comment::find(1);

    //In the comment relationship, save a new post
    $post->save();
    return ("Post Added");
    }
```

> web.php

```
Route::get('/add-post',[MainController::class,'addPost']);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models

Answer (score 0):

```
$post = Post::create([
  'title' => 'test title',
  'description' => 'test description',
  'status' => 1,
  ]);

$post->comment()->create([ 'body' => "test body",'user_id' => 1]);
```